# Как в Django ListView через orm обратится к конкретному экземпляру модели?

Tags: python, django

мне нужно реализовать проверку, есть ли у конкретного поста и текущего юзера записи в таблице `Vote`, если есть записи, то нужно узнать какое значение в столбце `vote` таблицы `Vote` (0 не нравится, 1 нравится). Я при помощи этого в шаблоне устанавливаю на палец вверх или палец вниз активный стиль css.

Я это реализовал в `DetailView`, но столкнулся с проблемой в `ListView`, так как не могу получить id поста.

Мой код:

**Модель:**

```py
class Vote(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,
                             related_name='postid',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             default=None,
                             blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,
                             related_name='userid',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             default=None, blank=True)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**Метод, который я пытаюсь использовать в `ListView` context:**

```py
def get_vote(self):
    votes = Vote.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id, post=post)
    if len(votes) == 0:
        return 'not_vote'
    if len(votes) == 1:
        if votes[0].vote == 0:
            return 'down'
        if votes[0].vote == 1:
            return "up"
        else:
            raise TypeError('Ошибка в Vote')
    context['vote'] = get_vote(self)
```

Я новичок в Django, буду рад помощи.

Comment: Так вам надо это для каждого поста сделать? Или для какого-то конкретного (какого?)?

Comment: Для каждого , я перебираю посты в шаблоне циклом for, как раз в ListView. Мне нужно проверить каждый из постов по отношению к юзеру и в зависимости от значения его выбора указывать(или нет) стиль css(чтобы если пользователь поставил  палец вверх"нравится" или палец вниз 'не нравится', кнопка была другого цвета (Щас когда пользователь делает выбор, то Ajax добавляет стиль, но при обновлении страницы стили выбора пропадают), поэтому я хочу прописать его выбор в шаблоне через тег if